# Why does rank$(A)$ + null$(A)$ = dim$(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

This may be a stupid question. From what I understand, the rank is the property of a matrix, whereas the dimension is a property of the vector space. How can they be relatable?

If they are relatable, why is the nullspace included in this equation? My understanding of the dimension of a vector space is that it is the basis vectors. Including the null space would therefore add linearly dependent vectors?

Comment: The dimension of a vector space is the number of vectors in a basis, not any particular basis.

Answer (score 3):

A matrix is just a rectangle of numbers. Matrices are interesting because they represent linear transformations between vector spaces (once bases are chosen). Any property of matrices (in the context of linear algebra) worth looking at is in fact a property of linear transformations. The theorem you state rephrased in terms of linear transformations is that if $T\colon V\to W$ is a linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces, then $dim(V)=dim(ker(T))+dim(im(T))$. If you think of the dimension as the number of degrees of freedom, then this theorem says that a linear transformation preserves the degrees of freedom in the sense that all of the degrees of freedom are clearly accounted for: whatever $T$ killed + the image of $T$ recovers precisely the degrees of freedom in the domain.

As a side note: matrices are, sometimes, a convenient computational aid but rarely can one understand what is going on just from considering a rectangle of numbers. It is the linear transformations we care about and very often they carry the most illuminating information. Thus, always think in terms of linear transformations and remember that a matrix is simply a representation of one.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write this answer Ittay. I am teaching myself linear algebra and I am struggling to develop intuition. What is im(..), and what is the interpretation of dim(ker(T)) and dim(im(T))? How does dim(...) relate to rank(...)?

Comment: @MichaelBarton $\operatorname{im}$ is short for “image”—the set of vectors that can be “reached” by $T$. It’s equal to the *column space* of the associated matrix. $\ker$ stands for “kernel’: the set of vectors mapped to zero, what this answer refers to as “killed” by $T$. This is the same as the *null space* of the associated matrix. The rank of a matrix or linear transformation is the dimension of its image—the number of degrees of freedom, as Ittay Weiss says—which is indeed the same as the number of basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$rank(A)= \dim \{Ax: x \in V\}$ and $null(A)= \dim \{x \in V: Ax=0\}$

Comment: Thank you for you hint. Does dim{...} mean the number vectors in a basis? And therefore dim⁡{x∈V:Ax=0} is the number of basis vectors when Ax=0?